# Lookup/Query confusion - Really stuck but I figure it's not as hard as I'm making it

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

So, I have an imported sheet with colums like so...

| Name | SAT1045 | SAT1200 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dave | 0 | 1 |
| Angela | 0 | 1 |
| Stuart | 1 | 0 |

From this I need to generate attendance lists displaying the times (SAT1045) followed by those attending.  Those attending have a 1 in that column. So as a example:

**SAT1045**
Stuart

**SAT1200**
Dave
Angela

The other trick is there are multiple days and times, so I have used Data Validation to populate a dropdown on a fresh sheet.  So the chosen date would populate the list below it.

I just don't know what Query or Lookup function to use to strip the data from the import as there is also a lot of nonsene data in the import between the Names and the dates.

Can anyone help?

I have tried numerous levels of Query's and Lookups but my head just can't get around this one

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use a second sheet for the attendance.
If the `Name` cell in your exemple is `A1`, you cvan have someting like this in your second sheet:

**In A1 (second sheet) :**

```
=Sheet1!B1
```

this will set the header at the corresponding time

**In A2 (second sheet) :**

```
=QUERY(
    Sheet2!$A$1:$C$4,
    CONCATENATE("select A where ",SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(B2),4),1,""),"=1")
    ,0
)
```

this will get the names for the time set in the first row.

Than tou only hace to drag those to for every attendance to get.

***Edited to adjust to OP's comment***

```
=QUERY(
    [table of time and 0/1],
    CONCATENATE(
        "select A where ",
        SUBSTITUTE(
            ADDRESS(
                1,
                COLUMN(
                    INDEX(
                        [Row with all times],
                        match(
                            [Reference of the cell with the dropdown],
                            [Row with all times],
                            0
                        )
                    )
                ),
                4
            ),
            1,
            ""
        ),
        "=1"
    ),
    0
)
```

this formula here allow you to get the attendants based of the time in the cell above it.

So, from the left to the right :
`match` here will look through the different time based on the selected one in the cell above, and will return the reference of the cell;
The whole part `Substitute(Adress(Column(Index())))` will return the letter of the column in wich the selected tim is. this allow to have a valid `Query` as it requiress the letter of the column to work;
And finally the `Query` returns every `name` where the value is `1` in the column corresponding to the chosen time

The values of `[Row with all times]` should always be the same. In your case, either `1:1` or `$AC$1:$AP$1`. In the first case it's just that if you add a row for a new `time` it'll take it into acount

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  So to clear it up a bit more, on import the Columns I need to use are:

First Name - Col O
Surname - Col P

SAT1045 - Col AC ... and so on through to ... SUN1800 - Col AP

I want to have a new sheet as you suggested.  I have created a dropdown that let's me select the times (SAT1045, SAT1200 etc.).  What I would love to happen is for the Names to appear below the time selected from the dropdown starting in A3 listing vertically, so..

SAT1045

Dave
Angela
Stuart

Hope that makes sense.  I'm really not great at this stuff...yet!

Comment: updated for the dropdown menu

Comment: FANTASTIC - It works like a charm.  Would buy you a drink if I could!

Comment: No problem :D clearly wouldn't say no ( what you could do instead is accept my answer and upvote it ;)